# Guava cache behavior for requests when an async reload thread is already in progress

Tags: java, caching, guava

From the guava documentation [here](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#refreshAfterWrite-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) , when a request is received for a cache key for which refresh time has expired, it starts an asynchronous thread to refresh the key if it is setup that way and returns the existing value. What I did not get from the documentation is what happens when another request is received immediately after the first one and the previous async thread for refresh is still running? Will it -

1. Return the old data AND start another async thread for refresh OR
2. It sees another refresh thread is running and it just returns the old data without spawning a new thread.

If the behavior is first one, I would be concerned if the request rate is very high, it might end up utilizing significant resources in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the JavaDoc for `refreshAfterWrite` states,

> The semantics of refreshes are specified in LoadingCache.refresh(K)

This clarifies the behavior as,

> Returns without doing anything if another thread is currently loading the value for {@code key}. If the cache loader associated with this cache performs refresh asynchronously then this method may return before refresh completes.

The cache is smart enough to do (2) and you could easily verify that by writing a simple unit test.